# php pdo prepares query but does not execute it

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm really new to php and pdos. A friend of mine basically created a pdo class and a couple of examples of how to use it and that's been working great for me. But now I want to do a query that uses the `BETWEEN` mysql keyword and returns anything that matches the criteria but it just comes up blank. I have created `mysql_query.log` file and from what I can gather from it the query gets prepared but not executed. I'll show you my findings from the log in a second, let me quickly just show you my code:

```
$newSlot = array(
    "fromDate" => $db->mysql_escape_mimic($startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
    "untilDate" => $db->mysql_escape_mimic($endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
  );

  $query = "SELECT * FROM schedule_slot WHERE (startDate BETWEEN :fromDate AND :untilDate) OR (endDate BETWEEN :fromDate AND :untilDate);";
  $result = $db->prepare($query);
  $slot = null;
  if($result == 1) {
    $result = $db->execute($newSlot);
    if($result == 1) {
      $slot = $db->fetch();
    }
  }
  print "slot: " . $slot["startDate"];
```

Here's the applicable part of the log (which I tidied up a bit):

```
161010 20:59:31     
    2 Connect   root@localhost as anonymous on test
    2 Prepare   SELECT * FROM schedule_slot WHERE (startDate BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR (endDate BETWEEN ? AND ?)          
    2 Close stmt                
    2 Quit
```

And here's an example from the log of a query that actually worked out fine for me:

```
161010 21:01:07     
    3 Connect   root@localhost as anonymous on test         
    3 Prepare   INSERT INTO schedule_slot(startDate, endDate) VALUES(?,?)
161010 21:01:08     
    3 Execute   INSERT INTO schedule_slot(startDate, endDate) VALUES('2016-10-11 13:35:00','2016-10-11 14:35:00')         
    3 Close stmt                
    3 Quit
```

Let me know if you want me to edit the pdo code or anything else in but as far as I can tell it's a standard pdo class. Please let me know why my query isn't returning anything

**Edit**: Here's the pdo class, filename `dbpdo.php`:

```
<?php

class dbpdo {

private $_connection;
private $_statement;

public function __construct( ) {}

public function connect( $host, $username, $password, $database ) {
    $connect = 'mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database.';charset=utf8mb4';
    $this->_connection = new PDO($connect, $username, $password);
    $this->_connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $this->_connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}

public function __destruct() {
    if ($this->_connection)
        $this->_connection = null;
}

public function query($query){
    try {
        return $this->_connection->query($query);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function fetch(){
    try {
        return $this->_statement->fetch();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function prepare($query) {
    try {
        $this->_statement = $this->_connection->prepare($query);
        return 1;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function execute($array) {
    try {
        $this->_statement->execute($array);
        return 1;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function mysql_escape_mimic($inp) {
    if(is_array($inp))
        return array_map(__METHOD__, $inp);

    if(!empty($inp) && is_string($inp)) {
        return str_replace(array('\\', "\0", "\n", "\r", "'", '"', "\x1a"), array('\\\\', '\\0', '\\n', '\\r', "\\'", '\\"', '\\Z'), $inp);
    }
    return $inp;
}
}
```

Comment: What is `mysql_escape_mimic` and if you are using a prepared parameterized query statements, why are you doing anything like that anyway

Comment: You have 4 parameters and only 2 values in the array!

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM schedule_slot WHERE (startDate BETWEEN :f1 AND :u1) OR (endDate BETWEEN :f2 AND :u2);";` and chnage the array of values accordingly to hold 4 parameters

Comment: You should also be checking the status of all pdo calls

Comment: I'll edit in `mysql_escape_mimic`, and I tried that query you wrote but it also comes up blank, I'm not sure where I should declare `f1, f2, u1 and u2`? Also, how do I check the status of pdo calls?

Comment: [**RT?M**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First when things are going wrong add these 2 lines after your `<?php` tag as far to many people develop on LIVE servers where error reporting will of course be turned off, and assume there is nothing wrong with their code when in reality it is generating lots of errors.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Then set PDO to throw exceptions

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$newSlot = array(
                    ":f1" => $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
                    ":u1" => $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
                    ":f2" => $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
                    ":u2" => $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                );


$query = "SELECT * FROM schedule_slot 
            WHERE (startDate BETWEEN :f1 AND :u1) 
               OR (endDate BETWEEN :f2 AND :u2)";

$result = $db->prepare($query);
// now execute the prepared query on $result not $db
$result = $result->execute($newSlot);

$row = $result->fetch_object();

print "slot: " . $row->startDate;
```

Now if any errors occur you will see them on the page, or you will see an exception throw, but not caught, so that will also show on the web page

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I couldn't get the `db->setAttribute...` part working but I editing my array to look like yours fixed it.